# Placing a paper under review on my website?

Tags: publications, paper-submission

I am wondering if it would be fine for me to place my paper that is currently under review on my website? Since I did not see there is any specific instruction on this issue in the journal's website, my main concern is I am not sure if this contradicts any ethical rules.

Comment: In many fields it is quite common to circulate papers freely while review is underway, or even before submitting, so there is no inherent ethical problem.  But one possible objection would be if the journal uses double-blind review.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Thanks so much. Since this journal implements no double-blind reviewing policy, I guess I am free of "accusation" :)

Comment: Check the terms, some journal submission asked if you have released the work in any form. If that includes releasing on the Internet, then I would hold on to it until there is a decision. I doubt you can find that in the website, it's usually done through checking off some questions when submitting the work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer depends critically on your field: you need to talk to your advisor and find out what the general policy is.  Three examples along the spectrum of radically different possibilities:

- In mathematics, theoretical physics and theoretical computer science, papers under review are circulated publicly long before being published.  This practice is a key motivator behind [arXiv](http://arxiv.org).
- On the more empirical/applied side of computer science, making a paper under review publicly available wouldn't be a problem except in case of double-blind review, but would generally be considered rather gauche.  Circulating privately in advance, on the other hand, is quite accepted.
- Many biology journals aim to [tightly control the timing and release of information](https://embargowatch.wordpress.com/). In many cases, posting a paper under review could actually be considered prior publication, and result in the paper being disqualified as a submission and automatically rejected.

Find out which are the practices of your field and follow them.